# Why does stamen terrain return an error in my web app code?

Tags: python

code:

```py
import folium
map = folium.Map(location=[38.58, -99.09],zoom_start=6, tiles="Stamen Terrain")
map.save("Map1.html")
```

error:

```
File "C:\Users\Koku Lwanga\PycharmProjects\webmap\map1.py", line 2, in <module>
    map = folium.Map(location=[38.58, -99.09],zoom_start=6, tiles="Stamen Terrain")
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Koku Lwanga\PycharmProjects\webmap\venv\Lib\site-packages\folium\folium.py", line 303, in __init__
    tile_layer = TileLayer(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Koku Lwanga\PycharmProjects\webmap\venv\Lib\site-packages\folium\raster_layers.py", line 145, in __init__
    raise ValueError("Custom tiles must have an attribution.")
ValueError: Custom tiles must have an attribution.
```

I tried to add points to the map using tiles but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem and the new way of adding tiles solved the error:
[Folium doesn't show map with version 0.14.0 and error with version 0.15.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77499014/folium-doesnt-show-map-with-version-0-14-0-and-error-with-version-0-15-0/77734659#77734659)

By the way "Stamen Terrain" is now called "Stadia.StamenTerrain" and no longer free to use.