# Folium doesn't show map with version 0.14.0 and error with version 0.15.0

Tags: folium

I used folium before and it was no problem.

However, today i use it and found that no map shows with version 0.14.0.

And i get error with version 0.15.0 as follows: (ValueError: Custom tiles must have an attribution.)

Without tiles, i can see map, however, i can't use specific tiles.

How i can solve this problem?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.

Old way of coding:

```
    folium.TileLayer('Stamen Terrain').add_to(m)
```

Throws error:

```
    raise ValueError("Custom tiles must have an attribution.")
    ValueError: Custom tiles must have an attribution.
```

Two new ways of adding tile sets:

1. Addressing a common one directly ([link 2](https://xyzservices.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html)):

```
    from xyzservices.lib import TileProvider
    
    provider = TileProvider.from_qms("OpenTopoMap")
    folium.TileLayer(provider).add_to(m)
```

2. Importing one including url and attr ([link 1](https://xyzservices.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html)):

```
    import xyzservices.providers as xyz
    
    providers = xyz.flatten()
    
    selection = ['CartoDB.Positron',
                 'CartoDB.Voyager'
                 ]

    for tiles_name in selection:
        tiles = providers[tiles_name]
        folium.TileLayer(
            tiles=tiles.build_url(),
            attr=tiles.html_attribution,
            name=tiles.name,
        ).add_to(m)

    folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
```

Or manually using custom ones ([link 2](https://xyzservices.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html)):

```
    from xyzservices.lib import TileProvider
    
    public_provider = TileProvider(
        name="My public tiles",
        url="https://myserver.com/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
        attribution="(C) xyzservices",
    )
    folium.TileLayer(public_provider).add_to(m)
```

Links:

https://xyzservices.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html
[https://xyzservices.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xyzservices.TileProvider](https://xyzservices.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html)

Stamen maps are no longer free to use: don't use them, they're intentionally blocky as a result